# Test js code with http requests

Tags: javascript, reactjs, karma-jasmine

I have an app that has been written with react + flux + webpack + karma. The main app logic sits in the stores and some other objects, which are the only things I test, components testing will come later.

Some of stores and objects are using http requests using xhr library. How to I make these not fail, and mock the data that is supposed to be given?

Comment: use nock, http://github.com/pgte/nock, to mock your http calls.

Comment: nock appears to be for Node.js. Can you browserify nock?